# How to concatenate char with numbers via loops

Tags: python

I have make a set of names in this form: `'s1', 's2', ..., 's100'`. I thought I can do that easily via looping:

```
for i in range(100):
    print ('s'.format(i+1))
```

`format` here does not append the numbers. I only get `ss..ss` without the numbers being concatenated in single quote. I know how to do this in Java but I am not that much expert in Python. Thank you

Comment: I sense an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Also, couldn't you have read the documentation for the function you're trying to use?

Comment: or just use concatenation `print 's'+str(i)`  -- python2.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a *placeholder* in the [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

> Perform a string formatting operation. The string on which this method
>   is called can contain literal text or *replacement fields delimited by
>   braces {}*. Each replacement field contains either the numeric index of
>   a positional argument, or the name of a keyword argument.

```
for i in range(100):
    print ('s{0}'.format(i+1))
```

Comment: This works GREAT. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

If you use 3.6, then you can take advantage of the new 'Literal String Interpolation', and do the following:

```
for i in range(100):
    print(f's{i + 1}')
```

For more details on this feature, check out [PEP 498 -- Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use Python 2x since my simulation supports it. Is there a workaround of that?

Comment: in that case, just do what @alecxe suggested.